# Alert not coming using timer in updatepanel

Tags: c#

I am using c# for programming!

Below is my aspx code where I am using timer control in UpdatePanel.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="20000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidCurrentDate" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidTripIds" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidTripDetails" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="currPageNo" runat="server" Value="1" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And below is the code of my aspx.cs for timer_tick event.

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtTrips = null;
    WEX.Prototype.Data.TripDA tripDA = new WEX.Prototype.Data.TripDA();
    TripSummaryBO tripSummaryBO = new TripSummaryBO();
    string tID = hidTripIds.Value.TrimStart(',');

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tID))
    {
        string[] tripIDs = tID.Split(',');
        string status = string.Empty;

        foreach (string tripID in tripIDs)
        {
            tripSummaryBO = tripDA.getTripSummary(Convert.ToInt32(tripID));
            if (tripSummaryBO.tripLastEditedOnDate > Convert.ToDateTime(hidCurrentDate.Value))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
                {
                    status = tripSummaryBO.tripID.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    status = status + "," + tripSummaryBO.tripID.ToString();
                }
                if (cnt == 0)
                {
                    hidTripDetails.Value = ("Trip name-" + tripSummaryBO.tripName + " was modified by user " + tripSummaryBO.tripLastEditedBy);
                }
                else
                {
                    hidTripDetails.Value = hidTripDetails.Value + "--" +("Trip name-" + tripSummaryBO.tripName + " was modified by user " + tripSummaryBO.tripLastEditedBy);
                }
                cnt = cnt + 1;
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
        {
            string alertMessage = "alert('" + hidTripDetails.Value + "');";
            Guid numb = Guid.NewGuid();
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(upTripsGrid, upTripsGrid.GetType(), numb.ToString(), alertMessage, true);
            WEX.Prototype.Service.WSProxies WSProxies = new WEX.Prototype.Service.WSProxies();
            dtTrips = WSProxies.Build();
            Session["AllTrips"] = dtTrips;
            dtTrips = (DataTable)Session["AllTrips"];                
            BuildGridViewControl(dtTrips);
        }            
        hidCurrentDate.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can see that I am using below code for showing alert however its not coming up!

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(upTripsGrid, upTripsGrid.GetType(), numb.ToString(), alertMessage, true);
```

Please suggest!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is "upTripsGrid" in you code?
If you're using this code, with the above aspx-code, try using "UpdatePanel1" instead of "upTripsGrid"?

Comment: Thanks Buddy I just missed that! Cheers